# Best OLAP option for ASP.NET MVC and Oracle 11g

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, olap

We're working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 project with Oracle DB (11g). Customer has asked us to add ad-hoc reports (OLAP) to our system, so we're looking at possible options. User interface should be integrated into existing ASP.NET MVC web-site and data source should be Oracle DB. What is the best available options for such configuration?

Comment: maybe a good question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is rather late (being well over a year after the post!) but I would strongly recommend the OLAP option that is embedded into the 11g database.

Oracle have wrapped it in all sorts of crud and provided some not very good client tools (e.g. the OLAP worksheet) but the underlying engine, based on a tool originally called Express, has an extremely good pedigree and remains one of the best on the market. Performance is great, it has an excellent and fully-featured language and costs a fraction of Oracle's own Hyperion offering.

Best of all, it is embedded in the Oracle database allowing (relatively) easy transfer of data from one to the other (although they are still surprisingly much at arm's length, given how long the technology has been owned by Oracle).

Having had relatively limited success with the client tools provided by Oracle, we have tended to go back to basics and define/populate objects manually in the OLAP cube - although most of our applications tend to involve modelling/forecasting so require write-back, which is a strength of Oracle OLAP, but not well supported by the client tools as Oracle would rather you used the more expensive Hyperion.

Comment: Terry this is the perfect Stack Overflow way to keep questions up to date. Thanks for the contribution.